# Accessing functionality in JNI DLL through ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, java-native-interface

I'm attempting to use the `CreateObject` function within ColdFusion to access functionality within a DLL through JNI. I've managed to get ColdFusion to load the DLL OK using the java.lang.System.load function, but am not sure how to then access the functions contained within this method.

My current code:

```
<cfset CreateObject("java","java.lang.System").load("C://Path//To//JniDll.dll")> 
<cfset JniObject = CreateObject("java","Organisation.product.package")>
```

Which fails on line 2 with the error

```
Object Instantiation Exception. 
Class not found Organisation.product.package
```

It's possible I'm accessing these methods incorrectly, but haven't been able to find any information about using JNI in ColdFusion on the web.

Thanks for your help,

Tom

Comment: What kind of dll? Is there a reason you cannot use createObject(".net") or createObject("com") ? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-715f.html

Comment: Hi Leigh, I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by "what kind of dll?" It has been provided to me as a means of integrating with a particular product I need to use in a project. The provider suggests it as the "best" for integrating with their project using Java. Presumably it's not possible to integrate any DLL with using .net or com objects - I assumed this one had been specifically written for JNI.

Comment: I just meant did they provide a .net (or even com) dll that could be used with createObject(). Knowing nothing about the product, that may be a silly question ;)

Comment: Hi Leigh, as far as I'm aware they only provide a standard DLL which can be accessed by C etc. and a JNI "wrapper" DLL which I the one I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get access to the methods in that DLL just by registering it AFAIK. Either you get supplied a Java wrapper (probably as a JAR) which will then use the DLL, or you have to see what COM interfaces the DLL exposes and call them via createobject(type="COM"), as others have suggested.

From the looks of your code and error, you're expecting a Java class Organisation.product.package to be present and CF can't see it, so I'd take a look in the CF administrator and see which paths are in your classpath. Drop the JAR I assume you have into CF's lib folder and restart CF and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information - this makes things a bit clearer. Firstly, I don't have a JAR file - I've been provided with a JNI dll suitable for integrating into a Java project. I was hoping I'd be able to use this directly from ColdFusion without needing to write a wrapper. I will review the dll to see if it has a COM interface, though i I think it is unlikely as it's been provided specifically as a JNI interface to Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make it work in java first. After that you place the generated jar file in the correct coldfusion lib directory and load (the java class) using CreateObject. The java class should be responsible for the dll binding.

Comment: Another way to go if you just want a native C++ interface to coldfusion is to use their CFX methods. It might be easier in some cases.

Comment: Hi Bengt - thanks for these suggestions - I'm currently just looking for the quickest way to work with what I have (a standard C++ DLL and a JNI wrapper DLL). Ideally I don't want to have to write another Java wrapper if it's possible to use the JNI dll directly in ColdFusion. If not, I'll look at building a wrapper either in Java or CFX methods.

Comment: @Loftx - I am not familiar with JNI. But it is often easier to get java code running "in java" first. Even if you do not end up using a java wrapper, troubleshooting is much easier using an IDE like Eclipse. Once you get things running, translate the working code to CF. Did they provide you with any java examples?